# XeTeX (via TexShop) font rendering partially broken on Snow Leopard

Tags: latex, fonts, osx-snow-leopard, xetex

Certain elements (such as `grqq{}` quotes or decimals from the `dcolumn` package) are missing when rendering with TexShop and XeTeX on Mac OS X 10.6.1 (Snow Leopard). Switching to the `dvipdfmx` engine did not help, it only misses other characters. My TexShop version is 2.26 (latest atm. I believe).

The problem persists for the couple of fonts I tried. Prior to Snow Leopard I had no problems at all. Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: yet another reason i haven't made the jump to snow leopard yet. :D
Quicksilver still doesn't work well from what I read... and I'd be lost without it.

Comment: @Mica: yep. The jump to 64-bit + X (in this case: font specs) did not work well for a couple of applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this problem will be fixed in MacTeX 2009, to be released soon. You can download a pre-release version here, if you're game:

```
http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html
```